# Logs of Next.js 13 with Node.js DevTools in windows are not working

Tags: node.js, next.js, cross-env

Logs of Next.js 13 with DevTools in windows are not working.

In the package.json I wrote this line:

`'cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev'`

With the previous version of Nextjs 12 it works.

I printed in a console log the process.env and with Nextjs 12 the result for the node variable is: `NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect"`, but with the Nextjs 13 the variable is: `NODE_OPTIONS=""`